# JavaFX - Can I kill or terminate a Task completely?

Tags: java, javafx, task

Currently, I have a program that executes a task (a file is imported). While executing, a Dialog pops up that shows the Progress with a ProgressBar. The Dialog contains a "Cancel" Button, that cancels the execution of the task when pressed. But if I start the task again (i try to import the file again after I canceled the last import), not only the task starts but the last task I cancelled continuos. I don't know if this has any effect on the output of the File, but still I would like to know: Can I kill or terminate a Task completely?

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {            
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                if(chat.getName().contains("KakaoTalk_")) {
                    String s = "";
                    String gesamt = "";
                    double laenge = 0;
                    try(BufferedReader brCount = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                        while((s=brCount.readLine())!=null) {
                            laenge++;
                            if(isCancelled()) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Fehler beim zählen");
                    }
                    double berechneLaenge = 0;
                    double berechneProzentLaenge = 0;
                    try(BufferedReader brCount = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                        while((s=brCount.readLine())!=null) {
                            if(isCancelled()) {
                                break;
                            }
                            berechneLaenge++;
                            berechneProzentLaenge = (berechneLaenge/laenge)*100;
                            prozentOderSo.set(String.valueOf((int)berechneProzentLaenge));
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Fehler beim zählen");
                    }
                    double momentanErreicht = 0;
                    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                        while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
                            momentanErreicht++;
                            updateProgress(momentanErreicht, laenge);
                            int p = (int)((momentanErreicht/laenge)*100);
                            prozentImported.set(p);
                            s = s.replace("ÃŸ", "ß");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¶", "ö");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¼", "ü");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¤", "ä");
                            s = s.replace("Ã„", "Ä");
                            s = s.replace("Ãœ", "Ü");
                            s = s.replace("Ã–", "Ö");
                            gesamt += s+"\n";
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        System.out.println("File not found");
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        System.out.println("IOException");
                    }
                    mp.eingabeSetText(gesamt);
                    setChat(mp.eingabeGetText());
                    getChat();
                } else mp.mhNichtPassendesFile();
                return null;
            }
        };
        mp.progressP().bind(task.progressProperty());
        mp.startFortschrittDialog();
        task.setOnFailed(mteh);
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        this.task = task;
        th.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't terminate the task. You can only cancel it and checking in this task if is cancelled with method `isCancelled()`.

Let me quote the documentation:

> Checking for isCancelled() in the loop body is critical, otherwise the developer may cancel the task, but the task will continue running and updating both the progress and returning the incorrect result from the end of the call method. A correct implementation of a Task will always check for cancellation.

Comment: So, thanks for the explanation, but how can I ensure that the task doesn't continue running? I put my current code in the question.

Comment: I think, you can check your thread status with method `isAlive()`.

Comment: @Korlimann You do see the first quoted sentence, yes?  “Checking for isCancelled() in the loop body is critical, otherwise the developer may cancel the task, but the task will continue running…” Check isCancelled() in your loops.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I just saw that I read the quote wrong, I thought it's critical and there is a better way to do this, my bad. I fixed the problem now.